# Remove Rarely Occurring Lines From Sequencing Fastq File

Tags: bash, awk, fastq

I have a text file that contains experimental data in 4-line long groups. I would like to remove those datapoints that are rare. So below is the first 8 lines file format, and this repeats for thousands of lines (the line numbers don't exist in the file):

```
1 Info_1
2 Sequence_1
3 Info_1
4 Info_1
5 Info_2
6 Sequence_2
7 Info_2
8 Info_2
9 Info_3
10 Sequence_3
11 Info_3
12 Info_3
```

So, lines 1-4 contains the information for sequence 1, lines 5-8 contains the information for sequence 2, and 9-12 for sequence 3... and so on. It is common in certain situations to remove any group of four lines that contain a sequence that is entirely unique or found fewer than 3 times.

What I would like to do is compare line 2 with lines 6, 10, 14, 18... and if it is found greater than 3 times, do nothing. If it is found 3 times or fewer, remove lines 1-4 and each group of 4 lines that contain the matching sequence. Then run the same comparison for every other line in the file.

So, if the in the above file, Sequence 1 and Sequence 3 match, and because that sequence has only been repeated < 3 times, delete each group of four lines, and the resulting file should look like this:

```
1 Info_2
2 Sequence_2
3 Info_2
4 Info_2
```

Here is what I have started with:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {
    if (FNR%4==2) {
    a[$1]++
    if (a[$1]<3) b[int(FNR/4)]=1
    }
    next}
b[int(FNR/4)]==0' inputFile inputFile > outputFile
```

This does not delete all of the lines which are found fewer than three times though. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Here is a real testable example as requested:
Input:

```
Info1
AAGC
Info1
Info1
Info2
AACT
Info2
Info2
Info3
AAGC
Info3
Info3
Info4
AAGC
Info4
Info4
Info5
AACT
Info5
Info5
```

Because `AAGC` occurs `>= 3` times but `AACT` occurs `<3` times the output should be:

```
Info1
AAGC
Info1
Info1
Info3
AAGC
Info3
Info3
Info4
AAGC
Info4
Info4
```

Hopefully that helps to clarify.

Comment: Don't tell us `if..` and show an **idea** of the input - show us some actual, testable input and the associated expected output. In your current example, Sequence_2 occurs less than 3 times and so should be deleted and Sequence_1 does NOT match Sequence_3 so we can't test a possible solution against that.

Comment: Sure I can add a real testable example

Comment: it is better, you should show `fastq` example (sequence DNA and quality) .... is it mandatory to use awk, or bash ? .... for this problem is better to use perl o python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending your script:

```
$ awk '
    (NR==FNR){ # First pass, record the count.
        if(FNR%4==2){a[$1]++}
        next;
    }

    (FNR%4){ # remember the group of 4 lines.
        r[FNR%4]=$0;
        next;
    }

    { # On every 4th line, check if the count is >= 3 & print the entire 4 line group.
        if (a[r[2]] >= 3) print r[1] "\n" r[2] "\n" r[3] "\n" $0 
    }' inputFile inputFile
```

Comment: Perfect, does exactly what I am looking for, and thanks for explaining the lines.

Answer (score 2):

for this question is better to use high-level programming language and specialized bioinformatic library, I use python and biopython

```
from Bio import SeqIO

input_file = open("input.fastq")

#to store sequence in dictionary using dna sequences as keys
#it consume RAM (if fastq is very very large, it could be a problem)
dict_seq = {}
for seq in SeqIO.parse(input_file, "fastq"):
  if not str(seq.seq) in dict_seq:
    dict_seq[str(seq.seq)] = []
  dict_seq[str(seq.seq)].append(seq)

#filter sequences
list_filter = [ dna for dna in dict_seq.keys() if len(dict_seq[dna]) >= 3]

#print output in fastq format
output_file = open("filter.fastq", "w")
for dna in list_filter:
  for seq in dict_seq[dna]:
    output_file.write(seq.format("fastq"))

output_file.close()
```

input.fastq

```
@EAS54_6_R1_2_1_413_324
CCCTTCTTGTCTTCAGCGTTTCTCC
+
;;3;;;;;;;;;;;;7;;;;;;;88
@EAS54_6_R1_2_1_540_792
TTGGCAGGCCAAGGCCGATGGATCA
+
;;;;;;;;;;;7;;;;;-;;;3;83
@EAS54_6_R1_2_1_443_348
GTTGCTTCTGGCGTGGGTGGGGGGG
+EAS54_6_R1_2_1_443_348
;;;;;;;;;;;9;7;;.7;393333
@EAS54_6_R1_2_1_413_789
CCCTTCTTGTCTTCAGCGTTTCTCC
+
;;3;;;;;;;;;;;;7;;;;;;;88
@EAS54_6_R1_2_1_413_329
CCCTTCTTGTCTTCAGCGTTTCTCC
+
;;3;;;;;;;;;;;;7;;;;;;;88
```

filter.fastq

```
@EAS54_6_R1_2_1_413_324
CCCTTCTTGTCTTCAGCGTTTCTCC
+
;;3;;;;;;;;;;;;7;;;;;;;88
@EAS54_6_R1_2_1_413_789
CCCTTCTTGTCTTCAGCGTTTCTCC
+
;;3;;;;;;;;;;;;7;;;;;;;88
@EAS54_6_R1_2_1_413_329
CCCTTCTTGTCTTCAGCGTTTCTCC
+
;;3;;;;;;;;;;;;7;;;;;;;88
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to python and biopython I had a quick look at biopython and it sounds like this will be very useful to me in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    numRecs += (NR%4 == 1 ? 1 : 0)
    rec[numRecs,(NR-1)%4 + 1] = $0
    cnt[$0]++
}
END {
    for (recNr=1; recNr<=numRecs; recNr++) {
        if (cnt[rec[recNr,2]] > 2) {
            for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=4; fldNr++) {
                print rec[recNr,fldNr]
            }
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Info1
AAGC
Info1
Info1
Info3
AAGC
Info3
Info3
Info4
AAGC
Info4
Info4
```